# How effective was child labor legislation in Victorian Europe?

Tags: europe, industrial-revolution, victorian

How effective was child labor legislation in Victorian Europe?

Effectiveness being counted in 'percent of working environments that actually complied', with 'Effective' being... 50% compliance? Or would the children just have went working somewhere else, if the workplace complied, as they needed the money?

Wikipedia for Child Labor Legislation:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_Acts

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_childhood#Children.27s_rights_under_the_law